# Web based debugging library for JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, interpreter, javascript-debugger

I am trying to make a web(Javascript) based JS interpreter and debugger for tutorial purposes. I am running the program on a nodejs server. The interpreter part is simply done by running the command `"node file.js"` on a `child_process.exec()`.

Can anyone suggest a good way to implement the debugger? If the user sets a breakpoint the program would run till that point and would show the values of the variable that have already been declared or changed till that point of  execution.

I tried to do this using the uglify-js module. I run the `UglifyJS.minify(<file.js>[,{options}])` to extract the variables used in the code and echo them out in the console.

I already came up with the following code for this purpose but I was looking for some available open source solution. Does anyone know about any library available for this purpose?

**File:** parser.js

```
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');

var allcode = new Object();
allcode.code = "";
allcode.vars = "";
var output = new Object();
output.data = "";
//THE BREAKPOINT MENTIONED BY USER
var tillLine = 3;
var i = 0;
var done = 0;
var filesuffix = "temp301";
var fileout = "output.log";
var child = Array();
var notAllowed = Array("console","log","eval");
fs.writeFileSync("./"+fileout, "");

fs.readFileSync('./demo.js').toString().split('\n').every(function (line) { 
    allcode.code += line + "\n";
    output.data[i] = "";
    allcode.vars = "";

    fs.writeFileSync("./"+filesuffix+".js", allcode.code);

    i++;
    //ADD CODE ONLY UPTO THE MENTIONED LINE
    if(i>tillLine)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});
//GET THE LIST OF USED VARIABLES
    var minified = UglifyJS.minify("./"+filesuffix+".js",{outSourceMap: "out.js.map"});
    var map = JSON.parse(minified.map);
    map.names.forEach(function(variable){
        if(notAllowed.indexOf(variable) == -1)
        {
            allcode.vars += "console.log('Value of "+variable+" is ' + "+variable+");\n";
        }
    });
    fs.appendFileSync("./"+filesuffix+".js", allcode.vars);
//EXECUTE THE DEBUGGING CODE
child = exec("nodejs " + "./"+filesuffix+".js");
done = 1;
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    output.data += data;
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    output.err += data;
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
    fs.writeFileSync("./"+fileout, JSON.stringify(output,null,'\t'));

    console.log(output.data);
    done = 0;

});
```

**FILE:** demo.js

```
var x = 9;
var a = "The sum is ";
var y = 10;
var z = y*y + x;
console.log(a + z);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
admin@tomcat-PC:~/Desktop/node_app$ nodejs parser.js 
Value of x is 9
Value of a is The sum is 
Value of y is 10
Value of z is 109
```

Answer (score 0):

Just of the top of my head, I'd try inserting a function call in the user code, at the point where the debugging action is expected.
The function would enumerate and print the local context variables along with any other useful info.
I would try to append the inserted code after the selected line semicolon, in order not to modify the line numbers below.